# On click, select more than one element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 buttons, where I have to select one in each row.

[image]

I have to choose one button of the first two and one button of the last two. So, two buttons.
I was able to make the JavaScript for the first two, but now i want to improve my code so I can select one of each button.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //show content by default
    $(".opt-container button:first-child").addClass("active");

    $('.opt-container button').click(function(){
      $('.opt-container button').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="opt-container" style="display: flex; margin: auto; padding-bottom:15px;">
    <button class="opt1-img active" dir="rtl">
        <img class="" src="../lp.8/img/venus.png">
        <p class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-top:10px; font-weight: 700;" dir="rtl">أنا امرأة</p>
    </button>
    <button class="opt2-img" dir="rtl">
        <img class="" src="../lp.8/img/mars.png">
        <p class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-top:13px; font-weight: 700;" dir="rtl">أنا رجل</p>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="opt-container" style="display: flex; margin: auto;">
    <button class="opt1-img active" dir="rtl">
        <img class="" src="../lp.8/img/loupe.png">
        <p class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-top:10px; font-weight: 700;" dir="rtl">وحيد</p>
    </button>
    <button class="opt2-img" dir="rtl">
        <img class="" src="../lp.8/img/wedding-rings.png">
        <p class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-top:13px; font-weight: 700;" dir="rtl">متزوج</p>
    </button>
</div>
```

How can I do this?
I'm novice to javaScript and all help is welcome. :)

Comment: what do you meany by _I can select one of each button._

Comment: @UsmanRana I have to choose one button of the first two(buttons) and one button of the last two. So, two buttons.

Comment: *"How can I do this"* ... do what exactly? Problem is not clear. Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: How do you choose which one of the two buttons to select in each container?  Is it random?

Comment: @charlietfl how to select more than one element, with the click event. See the buttons with the yellow background? Those are the buttons selected when you click. And right know my code only selects one button (of 4 buttons). I want to be able to select 2 buttons (of 4 buttons) with the click event.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 check what i just commented here above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the siblings with the active class.  In this case, it will be the "other" button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //show content by default
    $(".opt-container button:first-child").addClass("active");

    $('.opt-container button').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Here is a Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/45t7gpzj/

Comment: It works! Wonderful! I was so close! Thank you very much for the help! :D